# Failed to parse XML in AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: java, xml, android-studio

I am trying to run an app but the building is failing showing the following error: 
`Failed to parse XML in \app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml`

`org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 62; The prefix "android" for attribute "android:name" associated with an element type "uses-feature" is not bound.`

Here is my **AndroidManifest.xml** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="facebook.f8demo">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2.full" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".ClassifyCamera" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Sorry I did not paste it properly. Please have a look at it now.

Comment: There's gotta be more to that error message, yeah?

Comment: Yes. I'm getting another error message: `org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file: /app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 62; The prefix "android" for attribute "android:name" associated with an element type "uses-feature" is not bound.
`

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't seem applicable to what you've posted. Have you cleaned/rebuilt your project lately? Maybe Invalidate Caches/Restart?

Comment: yes I tried Invalidate Caches/Restart but still no luck.

Comment: What is your app min target version?

Comment: `minSdkVersion` 26 and `targetSdkVersion` 29

Answer (score 0):

Go to Build-> Clean project and Rebuild project. It works ...
OR (If clean project is not working/showing error)
Delete the build folder manually from "C Drive"

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried and now got stuck with lots of `libprotobuf` issues. Maybe the problem is associated with my C++ installation.